# I have an electric circuit issue

Tags: wiring

I have 120 volts at the junction box but only 17 volts at the light switch. What can cause this? I checked the circuit at the last junction box, that shows 120 volts. I checked at the switch, it shows 17 volts.

Answer (score 2):

The 17v is normally a phantom voltage, a bad connection or broken wire is normally the root cause  verify the connections are good and back stabs are not used at both points also check the other side of the wall for a receptacle if a common wall the problem can be there.